# mysqli_query возвращает null

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Когда я пытаюсь прочесть строки из таблицы mysql со следующим кодом, последняя переменная становится равна null

```
$hostnamedb = "localhost";
$databasedb = "здесьимябд";
$usernamedb = "здесьимя";
$passworddb = "здесьпароль";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostnamedb, $usernamedb, $passworddb, $databasedb);
$res = "SELECT * FROM `здесьимятаблицы` WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($res);
$ipres = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

При этом в phpmyadmin значения возвращаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_query принимает два параметра: строку подключения и сам запрос.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $res);
```

Так же проверяй подключение и выполнение запроса. Более подробно:
[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)